# Warning in PDOStatement: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepare

Maybe you can help me with this part of my code. I tried to make it works, but when I try to `UPDATE` always show me this error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]:
>   SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens in
>   /home/-----/public_html/soft/Admin/configuracion.php on line 264

the line 264 is:

```
// Execute the query
            $stmt->execute();
```

Below of:

```
 $stmt->bindParam(':page_meta_tag', $_POST['page_meta_tag']);
   $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
```

---

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
include '../include/update_config.php';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$action = isset( $_POST['action'] ) ? $_POST['action'] : "";
if($action == "update"){
        try{
             $query = "update CONFIGURACION set id = :id, nombre_clinica = :nombre_clinica, direccion = :direccion, telefono_clinica = :telefono_clinica, titulo_clinica = :titulo_clinica, logo = :logo, page_meta_tag = page_meta_tag where id = 1";

                $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

                $stmt->bindParam(':nombre_clinica', $_POST['nombre_clinica']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':direccion', $_POST['direccion']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':telefono_clinica', $_POST['telefono_clinica']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':titulo_clinica', $_POST['titulo_clinica']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':logo', $_POST['logo']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':page_meta_tag', $_POST['page_meta_tag']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);

                // Execute the query
                $stmt->execute();

                echo "Record was updated.";

        }catch(PDOException $exception){ //to handle error
                echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }
}

try {

        //prepare query
        $query = "select nombre_clinica, direccion, telefono_clinica, titulo_clinica, logo, page_meta_tag from CONFIGURACION where id = 1";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );

        //this is the first question mark
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['id']);

        //execute our query
        $stmt->execute();

        //store retrieved row to a variable
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $id = $row['id'];
        $nombre_clinica = $row['nombre_clinica'];
        $direccion = $row['direccion'];
        $telefono_clinica = $row['telefono_clinica'];
        $titulo_clinica = $row['titulo_clinica'];
        $logo = $row['logo'];
        $page_meta_tag = $row['page_meta_tag'];

}catch(PDOException $exception){ //to handle error
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}


?>
            <form class='form-horizontal' method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <fieldset>
                <legend><i class='icon32 icon-wrench'></i>Configuración General del Sistema</legend>

                <div class='control-group'>
                    <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Nombre de la Clínica</label>
                    <div class='controls'>
                        <input type='text' class='span6 typeahead' name='nombre_clinica' 
                            value='<?php echo $nombre_clinica;  ?>' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='control-group'>
                    <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Dirección</label>
                    <div class='controls'>
                        <input type='text' class='span6 typeahead' name='direccion' 
                            value='<?php echo $direccion;  ?>' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='control-group'>
                    <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Número de Teléfono</label>
                    <div class='controls'>
                        <input type='text' class='span6 typeahead' name='telefono_clinica' 
                            value='<?php echo $telefono_clinica; ?>' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='control-group'>
                    <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Viñeta de página web</label>
                    <div class='controls'>
                        <input type='text' class='span6 typeahead' name='titulo_clinica' 
                            value='<?php echo $titulo_clinica; ?>' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='control-group'>
                    <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Logo Clínica</label>
                    <div class='controls'>
                        <input class='input-file uniform_on' id='fileInput' name='logo' type='file' />
                        <br />
                        <img style='max-height:80px;' src='../images/<?php echo $logo; ?>' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='control-group'>
                    <label class='control-label' for='typeahead'>Meta tag del Software clínico</label>
                    <div class='controls'>
                        <input type='text' class='span6 typeahead' name='page_meta_tag' 
                            value='<?php echo $page_meta_tag; ?>' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='control-group'>
                    <div class='controls'>
                <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id ?>' /><input type='hidden' name='action' value='update' />
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Actualizar configuracion' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                </fieldset>
             </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed a `:` Change the query to:

```
$query = "update CONFIGURACION set 
  id = :id, 
  nombre_clinica = :nombre_clinica, 
  direccion = :direccion, 
  telefono_clinica = :telefono_clinica, 
  titulo_clinica = :titulo_clinica, 
  logo = :logo, 
  page_meta_tag = :page_meta_tag  // <--- here it was missing
  where id = 1";
```

Comment: I have another question...when I update the entry, the logo (jpeg,png,etc.) don't save it can you see if miss something in it?

Comment: Are you sure that all values are transmitted properly with POST ? What gives you `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: well to be honest PDO is really hard to me, because in mysql I always used these inside of the form:  `code`<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000" />
 <input data-clear-btn="true" class="element file" name="FOTO" id="file-2" value="nopic.jpg" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg"/>`code` and in php    `code` move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FOTO']['tmp_name'],$directorio.$FOTO);`code`   but in PDO this not working at all